# What is the difference between ColorScheme and ColorSchemeSeed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, color-scheme, flutter-theme

In Flutter, one can apply a theme to the app using ThemeData class. But there two propeties of this class that confuses me: ColorScheme and ColorSchemeseed. What's the difference between these two properties and when to use one or the other? Thanks.

Clear my Confusions on it.

Answer (score 0):

[**ColorScheme**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html) allows you to define each color property manually.

```
ColorScheme(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primary: Color(0xFF0095FF),
  onPrimary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  primaryContainer: Color(0xFFD3E4FF),
  onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFF001C38),
  secondary: Color(0xFF006495),
  onSecondary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  .....
);
```

[**ColorSchemeSeed**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.fromSeed.html) generates colorScheme based on one color.